# Dynamically change values based on user selected option django

Tags: html, django, forms, django-forms, jinja2

I'm trying to change a value based on the exchange rate selected by the user within the `<option>` tag. I don't want to save the form result to the database. I just want it to dynamically change whenever the user changes the currency option.

Say a user selects a currency from the below form with the options in the view:

**VIEW**

```
def view(request):

   currency_dict = {'EUR': 0.9154994049253867, 'JPY': 123.86706948640484, 'BGN': 1.7905337361530713, 'CZK': 22.375720955781375}

   cur = currency_dict.items()

   deposit = 10000

   context = {
   'currency_dict': currency_dict,
   'cur': cur,
   'deposit': deposit,
   }

   return render(request, 'coinprices/my-dashboard.html', context)
```

**HTML - FORM**

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <span>
    <h1>My Dashboard</h1>
        </span>
        <span>
        <form method="post">
            <label>Choose Currency:</label>
            <input list="ex-currency">
            <datalist id="ex-currency">
            {% for k, v in currency %}
                <option value="{{ k }}"></option>
            {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Submit</button>
        </form>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then based on the users selection, multiply the `{{ deposit }}` value by the `currency_dict[user_selected_currency]` and change the bold text (see below):

**DESIRED OUTCOME**

```
<span>
   <div><b>Total Investment {{ user_selected_currency }}</b></div>
   <span class="text-xl">${{ deposit * currency_dict[user_selected_currency] }}</span>
</span>
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: what is `currency` in your form ?

Comment: You can use JS to achieve this quite easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not a thing you can do with the `render` function you will need a `GET` request using `ajax` when the user changes the value, and then you can call a function based on the user option and return a valid response to the user this called "Chained Dropdown List" I found this amazing article that maybe can help you [How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)